# how to replace iframe with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, coldfusion

What I have here is `textarea` opens when I click to add the comment. So I don't want to use `iframe` anymore, can this be done with `JQuery` instead ? I was looking at the  `load()` function. How do I go about this ? thanks in advance!

my code

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr onclick="showhide('comment_#aggr_page_variable#'); return(false);" onmouseover="this.style.background='##e7eced';this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.background='##f0f3f4';" bgcolor="##f0f3f4">
        <td align="left" width="10">
            <img src="pics/button_triangle.gif" alt="" width="10" height="8" border="0">
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <font class="text_small">
            <font color="##777777">Click to add a comment</font></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

iFrame

```
<div id="comment_#aggr_page_variable#" style="display:none;">
        <div style="paddingo-bottom: 0px;">
            <iframe src="#submitted_display_new_comment.cfm?=#aggr_page_variable#" width="100%" height="81" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

textarea

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="comment" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; border: 1px solid ##dddddd; padding:2px; width:410px; height:51;"></textarea>
```

Comment: I tried helping you with this a few days ago. Your question is still incredibly unclear. You don't want to use an iFrame, can you use jQuery instead? Huh? What is your environment? Why does the ID contain so many `#`? Can you put up a fiddle or jsbin so we can see what you mean?

Comment: @elzi I can answer one question, the id contains # because Cold Fusion uses that as the `#variable#` and `#function()#` marker. It's one of those cases where the asker could do everyone a favor and share the rendered code rather than the raw source. Also, hex codes use `##` because that's how you escape `#` in CF.

Comment: Set up a demo or explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish and why your current code does not suffice. I still don't know what you want. What does the iFrame contain? What are you trying to load in using `load()`?

Comment: If I had to guess, it contains a form that is given a parameter from `aggr_page_variable`. Maybe post the contents of `submitted_display_new_comment.cfm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Updated, fixed a split I forgot.

Here's how I have this setup.

Each TR has a unique ID (in the format of `cl_#id#`) and shares a class, for the click event.

**JS Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/zct0c7ww/2

JQuery is used to populate a hidden field in the form, and the form is displayed in a div. The styling is generic but you can do with it what you like.

There's a bonus line in there that just shows you how it's working, you can remove it. On your form submit, or ajax submit, you'd use `#form.commentID#` and `#form.comment#`

```js
$(function() {
   $(".commentlink").on("click", function(e) {
       var cl_index = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
       $("#comment_box").show();
       $("#comment_box").css('visibility','visible');
       $("#commentID").val(cl_index);
       // This next line is just for demonstration.
       $("#commentTA").val("The hidden field in this form, 'commentID' has had it's value set to " + cl_index + ".");
   });
});
```

```css
#comment_box {display: none;
    visibility: hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr id="cl_1" class="commentlink" onclick="showhide('comment_#aggr_page_variable#'); return(false);" onmouseover="this.style.background='##e7eced';this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.background='##f0f3f4';" bgcolor="##f0f3f4">
        <td align="left" width="10">
            <img src="pics/button_triangle.gif" alt="" width="10" height="8" border="0">
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <font class="text_small">
                <font color="##777777">Click to add a comment</font></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="cl_2" class="commentlink" onclick="showhide('comment_#aggr_page_variable#'); return(false);" onmouseover="this.style.background='##e7eced';this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.background='##f0f3f4';" bgcolor="##f0f3f4">
        <td align="left" width="10">
            <img src="pics/button_triangle.gif" alt="" width="10" height="8" border="0">
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <font class="text_small">
                <font color="##777777">Click to add a comment</font></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    
<div id="comment_box">
        <div style="paddingo-bottom: 0px;">
            <form>
                <input type="hidden" name="commentID" id="commentID" value="0">
            <textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="comment" id="commentTA" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; border: 1px solid ##dddddd; padding:2px; width:410px; height:51;"></textarea>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement something like an ajax call that stores the comment in the database and appends the new comment to the div in the on sucess event of the ajax call.

As an example:

```
<td id="addComment" align="left">
    <font class="text_small">
    <font color="##777777">Click to add a comment</font></font>
</td>

<div id="comments"></div>
```

Ajax call:

```
$("#addComment").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"your-page-here", success:function(result){
    $("#comments").append(result);
  }});
});
```